# 2d array values aren't access in main method

Tags: java, arrays

How to access values stored in 2d array puzzle[][] in main class.
i am not able print these values in generate() but not in main method.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class generator {

 static   int  puzzle[][] = new int[9][9];

 public int[][] generate() {
     return puzzle;
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
    generator g = new generator ();
    g.generate();   
 }  
}
```

Comment: You are not printing anything.

Comment: _"i am not able print these vaues"_ - Where are the print statements?

Comment: " i am not able print these vaues in generate() but not in main method." - what do you mean?

Comment: I wish I could help but you have to many `not`'s in that last sentence and I am a bit confused

Comment: Please put more effort into explaining your question. This seems like a fairly simple problem that you _should_ get a bunch of answers for, _if_ we knew what you were talking about. In short `good exlpanation = quick answer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get from your question, you need the following to be put in the **main method**.

```
int[][] localPuzzle = g.generate();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        System.out.println(localPuzzle[i][j]);
    }
}
```

---

OR directly using `generator.puzzle[i][j]` should work too.

Hope this helps. Please clarify if you want something else.

Comment: If it worked for you, you might as well could accept the answer that you like so others would know that this question has been resolved; saving their time reading it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to access values stored in 2d array puzzle[][] in main class"*

My guess is you're having problems iterating through the array. Without giving you the answer, I will give you some things to think about and look at to help you in your learning.

- You need to iterate (loop) through the array. This is not like a regular array, where you can use one loop. Since it is a 2D array, you will need two loops. Take a look at [**Iterating through MultiDimensional Arrays**](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0080__Statement-Control/IteratingoverMultidimensionalArraysUseforeachstyleforonatwodimensionalarray.htm)
- For methods, you need to determine if you want the method to do the printing, or if you want the method to return something. If you want the method `generate()` to print, then the return type should be `void` and you need to add some `System.out.println()`s in a loop. The above link can show you how to iterate the array. If you did it *this* way, then calling `g.generate()` will work.
- Since you currently have the method `generate()` returning an array, then you need to do something like this

  ```
  int[][] array = g.generate();
  ```

  Then you need to iterate through it.

---

Read more on [**Defining methods**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)  and [**Loops**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)